# pyspark arrenge dataframe values in columns in given below way

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have below dataframe

[image]

I want to arrange value of column value_C , value_d. value_c is string type and value_d column is integer type. similarly I also have different datatype columns in my dataframe. I want to pivot the data based on value_c and value_d columns datatype into the new columns string_value and integer_value respectively. like below:

[image]

Similarly I have other datatypes columns also.

Answer (score 1):

There is inbuilt pivot() function in pyspark, but s per your requirement it is not possible by that, because this is not how pivot works. ref :- https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe/

I have solved it by below approach

```
#create two dataframes from original dataset
>>> df1=df0.select("cola","colb","value_c")
>>> df2=df0.select("cola","colb","value_d")
>>> df1.show()
+----------+------+-------+
|      cola|  colb|value_c|
+----------+------+-------+
|23-12-2011| apple|  hello|
|03-11-2011|orange|     Hi|
|13-08-2011|  rice|    How|
+----------+------+-------+

>>> df2.show()
+----------+------+-------+
|      cola|  colb|value_d|
+----------+------+-------+
|23-12-2011| apple|     45|
|03-11-2011|orange|     90|
|13-08-2011|  rice|     32|
+----------+------+-------+

#rename columns to seggragate during joins

>>> df1=df1.withColumnRenamed("value_c","string_value")
>>> df1.show()
+----------+------+------------+
|      cola|  colb|string_value|
+----------+------+------------+
|23-12-2011| apple|       hello|
|03-11-2011|orange|          Hi|
|13-08-2011|  rice|         How|
+----------+------+------------+

>>> df2=df2.select(col('cola').alias('coladf2'),col('colb').alias('colbdf2'),col('value_d').alias('integer_value'))
>>> df2.show()
+----------+-------+-------------+
|   coladf2|colbdf2|integer_value|
+----------+-------+-------------+
|23-12-2011|  apple|           45|
|03-11-2011| orange|           90|
|13-08-2011|   rice|           32|
+----------+-------+-------------+

#join dataframes

>>> df_join=df1.join(df2,df1.string_value == df2.integer_value,"full")
>>> df_join.show()
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+
|      cola|  colb|string_value|   coladf2|colbdf2|integer_value|
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+
|23-12-2011| apple|       hello|      null|   null|         null|
|03-11-2011|orange|          Hi|      null|   null|         null|
|13-08-2011|  rice|         How|      null|   null|         null|
|      null|  null|        null|23-12-2011|  apple|           45|
|      null|  null|        null|13-08-2011|   rice|           32|
|      null|  null|        null|03-11-2011| orange|           90|
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+

#replace all null from string columns with spaces so that we can concat  columns

>>> df_join=df_join.na.fill("")
>>> df_join.show()
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+
|      cola|  colb|string_value|   coladf2|colbdf2|integer_value|
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+
|23-12-2011| apple|       hello|          |       |         null|
|03-11-2011|orange|          Hi|          |       |         null|
|13-08-2011|  rice|         How|          |       |         null|
|          |      |            |23-12-2011|  apple|           45|
|          |      |            |13-08-2011|   rice|           32|
|          |      |            |03-11-2011| orange|           90|
+----------+------+------------+----------+-------+-------------+

>>> df_join=df_join.select(concat(df_join.cola,df_join.coladf2).alias("cola"),concat(df_join.colb,df_join.colbdf2).alias("colb"),"string_value","integer_value")

# required output
>>> df_join.show()
+----------+------+------------+-------------+
|      cola|  colb|string_value|integer_value|
+----------+------+------------+-------------+
|23-12-2011| apple|       hello|         null|
|03-11-2011|orange|          Hi|         null|
|13-08-2011|  rice|         How|         null|
|23-12-2011| apple|            |           45|
|13-08-2011|  rice|            |           32|
|03-11-2011|orange|            |           90|
+----------+------+------------+-------------+
```